# Customized Datagridview in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, controls

Is is possible to turn the header to bottom and start filling datagridview from bottom to top also something like chart? or is there any control with same function in VB.NET or C#

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any controls that does this but you could create your own... Load the data into a datatable then reading each row in output the html to display the data then output the 'header' last so that it appears on the bottom.